# How do I use paragraph to replace deprecated lineSpacing attribute

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using JasperReports.  When I generate my reports, I see this message a lot:

> JRAbstractStyleFactory - The 'lineSpacing' attribute is deprecated.
>   Use the <paragraph> tag instead.

I have not found any information on how to use the paragraph tag to replace lineSpacing; what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message says to replace an *attribute* with a *tag*.  That means, instead of this:

```
<style name="my_style" lineSpacing="Double" fontName="Univers" fontSize="9"/>
```

use this:

```
<style name="my_style" fontName="Univers" fontSize="9">
    <paragraph lineSpacing="Double"/>
</style>
```

And instead of this:

```
<textElement verticalAlignment="Top" lineSpacing="Double" markup="styled"/>
```

use this:

```
<textElement verticalAlignment="Top" markup="styled">
    <paragraph lineSpacing="Double"/>
</textElement>
```

That resolves all of the warnings.